# One-to-many : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'table_name' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 Tables , The 'menu' , 'ingredients' and 'menu-ingredients'(this one holds the foreign keys) check the image - [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qur8S.png)

Now , when I set the one-to-many relationship in the Menu.java class, hibernate somehow thinks that the **list** that I have the annotations on , is the table name :

Ingredients.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredients")
public class Ingredients {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "ingredient")
private String ingredientName;

@Column(name = "description")
private String ingredientDescription;
//Getters/Setters/Constructor
```

Menu.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

// Mapping To second table
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Ingredients> ingridients = new ArrayList<>();
// notice the name of this list 'ingridients' and then check the stacktrace.
```

main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RecipeappApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RecipeappApplication.class, args);

}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    Menu menu = new Menu("Pizza");
    menu.getIngridients().add(new Ingredients("Cheese","3 slices"));
    menu.getIngridients().add(new Ingredients("Bacon","3 pieces"));


    recipeRepository.save(menu);
    //recipeRepository.save() <- is just the entitymanager.persist() call.
}
```

and the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
...
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'recipe.menu_ingridients' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Why don't you define a join column?

Comment: After defining the @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id") : 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'menu_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database you have an associative table `menu_ingredient` so you need to map it using a `@JoinTable` :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "menu_ingredient",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
private List<Ingredients> ingredients;
```

- `@JoinTable` annotation is used to join two table using a third table (here `menu_ingredient`)
- `joinColumns`: The column of the third table related to the current entity (menu).
- `inverseJoinColumns`: The column of the third table related
  to associated entity (ingredients).

Comment: Oh thanks it works! :) Can you please explaint to me What JoinTable/JoinColumn/InverseJoinColumns does ? I'm trying to learn as I write the code so I don't really know what this annotation does .

Comment: I've updated my answer but you might want to look at tutorial on JPA entity relationship. For example [this](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/)